# Django ORM - get() with order_by()

Tags: python, django, orm

I want a mix of get() and order_by() like this

```
Model.objects.get(some=condition).order_by('name')
```

I want a single result (not filter) and ordered by name at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
Model.objects.filter(some=condition).order_by('name').first()
```

Answer (score 2):

get() wont take order_by() as get only returns one single object and you cannot order by one one row.

and for order by you need multiple rows for the ordering. use filter('your where clause').order_by('asc/desc')

hope it helps